# Wronskian of vector

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

$\vec Y'=AY, A_{2\times2}$ (constants over $\mathbb{R}$).

$\vec Y^{(1)}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{2x}\\ -e^{2x}\end{pmatrix}, W[\vec Y^{(1)},\vec Y^{(2)}](2)=e^3,W[\vec Y^{(1)},\vec Y^{(2)}](1)=e^2$. ($W :=$ wronskian).

My solution:

Define $\vec Y^{(2)}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}a\\ b\end{pmatrix},\vec Y'^{(2)}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}a'\\ b'\end{pmatrix} , a,b$ are functions.

$ W[\vec Y^{(1)},\vec Y^{(2)}]=\begin{vmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}e^{2x}\\ -e^{2x}\end{pmatrix} & y_2 \\
\begin{pmatrix}2e^{2x}\\ -2e^{2x}\end{pmatrix} & y'_2 
\end{vmatrix}=y'_2\begin{pmatrix}e^{2x}\\ -e^{2x}\end{pmatrix}-y_2\begin{pmatrix}2e^{2x}\\ -2e^{2x}\end{pmatrix}$

The wronskian is correct? I am not sure I am supposed to use vector in it since $e^2, e^3$ are scalars.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to solve for the other solution $\mathbf{Y}_2$ assuming $\mathbf{Y}_1$ is a solution to the planar system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wronskian of vector-valued functions $\{\mathbf{v}_1(x), \dots, \mathbf{v}_2(x)\}$ is defined as
$$ W\{\mathbf{v}_1, \dots, \mathbf{v}_n\}(x) = \det\begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{v}_1(x) & \dots & \mathbf{v}_n(x) \end{bmatrix}. $$
I assume that $\mathbf{Y}_1$ is a solution to the planar system and you want to solve for the other solution $\mathbf{Y}_2$. Following your notation, let $\mathbf{Y}_2(x) = (ae^{rx}, be^{rx})^T$, where I assume that the coefficient matrix $A$ has distinct real eigenvalues. The Wronskian of $\mathbf{Y}_1, \mathbf{Y}_2$ is given by
$$ W\{\mathbf{Y}_1, \mathbf{Y}_2\}(x) = be^{rx}e^{2x} + ae^{rx}e^{2x} = (a + b)e^{(2 + r)x}. $$
With the two given conditions on the Wronskian, we have $(a + b)e^{4 + 2r} = e^{3}$ and $(a + b)e^{2 + r} = e^2$. Equivalently, we have $(a + b)e^{2r} = e^{-1}$ and $(a + b)e^r = 1$. Solving these two equations, we get $r = -1$ and $a + b = e$.